# font-face issue in IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, font-face

I've started using font-face for a site. I've included a free font by Fontsquirrel called Chunk Five (http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/ChunkFive) that has support for IE (EOT font).

However when I implement it, some letters look 'squashed' which gives it a very ugly look.

Here's how it looks under Chrome (with text-shadow):
[image]

Here's how it looks under IE8:

[image: Font under IE8]

The e's, m's and 's look awful.

Is this an issue with the font? Or the CSS that I use? Or IE8?

Comment: Commenting because there isn't a real answer to this. It's a combination of factors: how well the font is hinted for screen rendering, the browser's text rendering engine, and (in the case of IE) the particular settings of the Windows ClearType engine. These categories on the TypeKit blog are good further reading: http://blog.typekit.com/category/optimizing-fonts-for-the-web/ and http://blog.typekit.com/category/type-rendering/

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I'll look into these links.

Answer (score 0):

May be add shadow with JS? 
CSS:

```
h1,  h2{ text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #ddd;}
```

Add Jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Add script file:

```
<script src="js/jquery.textshadow.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

JS code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// <![CDATA[
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery("h1, h2").textShadow();
    })
// ]]>
</script>
```

Jquery shadow plugin you can find here http://plugins.jquery.com/project/textshadow

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but unfortunately that doesn't account for the 'squashed' nature of certain letters and that is something that I'm looking to fix.

Answer (score 0):

I think it has something to do with odd font sizes. Try applying an even font size and the rendering should be correct.